# Custom constants in python humanname not working

Tags: python

I'm following the instructions [here on using the python-nameparser](https://code.google.com/p/python-nameparser/).

My problem is that for human names containing "assistant professor," I'm getting 'assistant' is the title, and 'professor' is assigned the role of first name.

```
>>> o.full_name = 'Assistant Professor Darwin Mittenchops'
>>> o
<HumanName : [
    Title: 'Assistant' 
    First: 'Professor' 
    Middle: 'Darwin' 
    Last: 'Mittenchops' 
    Suffix: ''
]>
```

Instead of

```
>>> o
<HumanName : [
    Title: 'Assistant Professor' 
    First: 'Darwin' 
    Middle: '' 
    Last: 'Mittenchops' 
    Suffix: ''
]>
```

Their example for adding custom constants to address this is:

```
>>> from nameparser import HumanName
>>> from nameparser.constants import PREFIXES
>>> 
>>> prefixes_c = PREFIXES | set(['te'])
>>> hn = HumanName(prefixes_c=prefixes_c)
>>> hn.full_name = "Te Awanui-a-Rangi Black"
>>> hn
<HumanName : [
    Title: '' 
    First: 'Te Awanui-a-Rangi' 
    Middle: '' 
    Last: 'Black' 
    Suffix: ''
]>
```

So, the following should allow me to make "assistant professor" a title:

```
>>> from nameparser import HumanName
>>> from nameparser.constants import TITLES
>>> titles_c = TITLES | set(["assistant professor"])
>>> hn = HumanName(titles_c=titles_c)
>>> hn.full_name = 'Assistant Professor Darwin Mittenchops'
>>> hn
<HumanName : [
    Title: 'Assistant' 
    First: 'Professor' 
    Middle: 'Darwin' 
    Last: 'Mittenchops' 
    Suffix: ''
]>
```

No dice.

```
>>> "assistant professor" in titles_c
True
```

So, I know it's there.  Just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I know it's a hard problem.  Do you have a better solution than one of the libraries that tries to do this?  I'd heard python-nameparser was one of the best we've got.

Comment: DSM, thanks.  I didn't check the code, but am surprised because the test suite has the multi-word title "secretary of state" :  ```$ ./tests.py "Secretary of State Hillary Rodham-Clinton"
    <HumanName : [
        Title: 'Secretary of State' ```

Comment: @Mittenchops: you're right-- I was looking at `return lc(value) in self.TITLES_C or value.lower() in self.PUNC_TITLES_C` in `is_title`, but the magic to combine title words is higher-level than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I read too quickly.  The code *can* handle combined words, but we need to add the words individually to the `titles_c` set, not as a unit.  Example:

```
>>> from nameparser import HumanName
>>> from nameparser.constants import TITLES
>>> titles_c = TITLES | set("assistant professor".split())
>>> hn = HumanName(titles_c=titles_c)
>>> hn.full_name = "Assistant Professor Darwin Mittenchops"
>>> hn
<HumanName : [
    Title: 'Assistant Professor' 
    First: 'Darwin' 
    Middle: '' 
    Last: 'Mittenchops' 
    Suffix: ''
]>
```

Comment: I think the key is that `prof` is in `TITLES`, but not `professor`. I had success by just adding `professor` to `titles_c`, and letting the chaining code combine that with `assistant`, which is already present by default. Confirmed; `Assistant Prof Darwin Mittenchops` parses as desired without having to pass any arguments to `HumanName`.

Comment: @chepner: that's true, but that doesn't explain why the OP's code didn't fix the problem.  The issue there is that the code doesn't split those titles after receiving them, so adding `"assistant professor"` to the set doesn't help any.

Comment: Right; I'm just pointing out why the seemingly acceptable "Assistant Professor" doesn't work without any modification. Actually, I got you confused *with* the OP; I probably should have commented on the question itself.